accessing indexed property of object?
so i have an object "Tabs" that i would to read the properties of. in this case, we have a count of 3, so there are 3 tabs. specifically trying to get the HeaderText property of the very first tab [0], as seen below:

i tried the following (based on the screenshot provided, you can see the name of the field is [0]:
var item = tabs.GetType().GetProperty("[0]").GetValue(tabs);

but i ended up with the error:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

here is the code im working with:
private void HeaderWasTapped(object sender, ItemHeaderTappedEventArgs e)
{

var PanelMap = new Controls.FlexMap();
var items = sender.GetType().GetProperty("Items").GetValue(sender);

// Reading non-public member of object
var tabs = items.GetType()
    .GetField("tabItems", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
    .GetValue(items);

var item = tabs.GetType().GetProperty("[0]").GetValue(tabs);

   // and some conditions here based on value of HeaderText
}

here is the type of var "Tabs":
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DevExpress.Maui.Controls.TabViewItem]

not sure how to get the HeaderText here...

Why are you using reflection for this? Surely you can just do a pattern match on the sender object and access its properties directly?

@ProgrammingLlama  yup,  ur right. I just did var item = ((List)tabs)[0]; and now i can access lol. feeling a little silly . anyways thx
